# How to set the map task timeout?

Tags: timeout, mapreduce

I tried this

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.task.timeout", "1000");
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

But I think it is not working.
I am trying to set mapred.task.timeout to 1000 and in the map class I am giving a " Thread.sleep(2000); " and expecting it to throw an exception. But it it running fine. Shouldn't this throw an exception?

Answer (score 5):

That is an old, deprecated config setting. It may be that you need the newer equivalent, `mapreduce.task.timeout`. Also, call `Configuration.setInt()` instead.

Comment: I tried that now. But still it runs without exception. How to verify that the timeout property got set?

Comment: Try setting this in conf/mapred-site.xml instead.